# Visual Studio Code adds yargs requirement for jest describe

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jestjs

Whenever I type `describe(`, Visual Studio Code automatically adds `const { describe } = require('yargs');` to the top.  The describe I'm wanting is from jest, not yargs.  How do I make this stop happening?

Comment: installing @types/jest might work

Comment: Thank you, @shabs.  That wasn't quite it, but it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a `jsconfig.json` file to the root of my project and put the following code in it:

```
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "include": [
            "jest"
        ]
    }
}
```

I restarted VS Code and now it no longer assumes `describe()` is from yargs.